# Restrict admin/content view by organic group membership

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I'm using D7 with organic groups. Have 7 groups each with their own content.  Anonymous users can view all content from any group.  Group admins can only edit the content from their own group.

When a group admin goes to admin/content they see all content items, though they can only edit their own.  Is there a way to restrict the output on admin/content so the group admin can only see their content on this page?  This would make it easier for them to review and manage their content as they would not need to page through all of the site content.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your needs correctly, you want to have a filtered list of content for og admins, don't you?

You could try to create a **[View](http://drupal.org/project/views)** for this particular purpose.

Try **[Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench)** module, if it suits your general need to organize content workflow.

Comment: Please note: Organic groups views - OG views module will be removed from OG core and becomes separate module. (http://drupal.org/project/og_views)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a module that implements hook_query_alter like:

```
function gestionsesion_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
global $user;
if (current_path() === 'admin/content'){    
    if ($query->hasTag('tablesort')) {              
        $query->condition('n.language', $user->language );      
    }
    }
}
```

Here we filter by user language but you could do it by role...